# error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 17: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, skaffold

Getting following error
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: YAML parse error on /templates/deploymentSomintec.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 17: mapping values are not allowed in this context
i don't see any problem in file deploymentSomintec.yaml can any one help on this to fix this issue

**file deploymentSomintec.yaml**

```
{{- if or (eq .Values.type "service") (eq .Values.type "local-dev-with-tests")  }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-service-test-runner
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Release.Name }}-service-test-runner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}-service-test-runner
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.global.service_name}}-service-test
        image: {{ .Values.service.imageservice.name }}:{{ .Values.service.imageservice.tag }}
        ports:
          - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.service_app_port }}
          - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.service_debug_port }}
{{ end }}
```

**file values.yaml**

```
service:
  global:
    service_name: service
  imageservice:
    name: "name" // this value will be override from skaffold file
    tag: "tag"  // this value will be override from skaffold file
  somintec_app_port: 3002
  somintec_debug_port: 9228
```

i am trying to deploy service using skaffold and helm in kube environment but getting error

Comment: If you run `helm template --debug` with the chart path and values-related options, it will print out the unparsed text.  Can you tell from inspection which line doesn't "look like" the rest of the file?

Answer (score 0):

One way to troubleshoot this is to use quotes around the `image` value which is the offending line if I'm reading correctly:

```yaml
image: `{{ .Values.service.imageservice.name }}:{{ .Values.service.imageservice.tag }}`
```

You'll see better the issue, it could be an extra space for instance. In which case you could use  `| trim`.